# read complicated .txt file into Matlab

Tags: string, matlab, file-io, textscan

I would like to read a .txt file into Matlab. 
One of the columns contains both letters and numbers.
(So I guess one way is to read this column is as string.)

The problem is I also need to find out numbers which are larger than 5 within that column.

e.g. The .txt looks like

```
12 1
21 2
32 7
11 a
03 b
22 4
13 5
31 6
```

i.e. Ultimately, I would like to get

```
32 7
31 6
```

How can I get it?? Any experts, please help!

Answer (score 4):

You can read the contents of the file into a cell array of strings using [TEXTSCAN](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/textscan.html), convert the strings to numeric values using [CELLFUN](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/cellfun.html) and [STR2NUM](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/str2num.html) (characters like `'a'` and `'b'` will result in the empty matrix `[]`), remove rows of the cell array that have any empty cells in them, then convert the remaining data into an N-by-2 matrix using [CELL2MAT](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/cell2mat.html):

```
fid = fopen('junk.txt','r');                        %# Open the file
data = textscan(fid,'%s %s','CollectOutput',true);  %# Read the data as strings
fclose(fid);                                        %# Close the file
data = cellfun(@str2num,data{1},'UniformOutput',false);  %# Convert to numbers
data(any(cellfun('isempty',data),2),:) = [];        %# Remove empty cells
data = cell2mat(data);                              %# Convert to N-by-2 array
```

The matrix `data` will now look like this, given your sample file in the question:

```
>> data

data =

    12     1
    21     2
    32     7
    22     4
    13     5
    31     6
```

And you can get the rows that have a value greater than 5 in the second column like so:

```
>> data(data(:,2) > 5,:)

ans =

    32     7
    31     6
```

Answer (score 0):

```
fid = fopen('txt.txt','r');  

Aout = []; 

while(1)    
    [a1,count1] = fscanf(fid,'%s',1);
    [a2,count2] = fscanf(fid,'%s',1);
    if(count1 < 1 | count2 < 1)
        break;    
    end
    if(~isempty(str2num(a2)) & str2num(a2) > 5 & (~isempty(str2num(a1))) )
        Aout = [ Aout ; str2num(a1) str2num(a2) ];   
    end
end

fclose(fid);
```

Violates the unspoken rule of growing a Matlab variable during a loop, but it's text processing anyway so you probably won't notice the slowness.

Edit: Had too many errors in previous version, had to start fresh.